# Linear Algebra. Bonus question Final Exam

Tags: linear-algebra

[image: Exam question]

This is from a practice final exam. I was wondering about the the 2nd part of A). It states that when v can't = O, it will form a basis. I'm having a tough time understanding that. How is that possible? I thought the rules for a subspace had to have 1) disclosure under scalar multiplication 2) A zero vector 3) disclosure under addition.

If you can't have a zero vector in the subspace, would this be incorrect to say that it could form a basis?

Comment: It isnt saying the zero vector isnt in there, just that the vector isnt identically the zero vector, a single vector spans a line in space as long as its not identically a zero vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the definition of span of a given set of vectors $$\{v_1, v_2, \dots,v_n\}$$
is given by:
$$\text{Span}\{v_1, v_2, \dots,v_n\}=\{u \; |\;u = c_1 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \dots +c_n v_n \text{ for}\; c_1,c_2,\dots,c_n \in \mathbb{R} \}$$ 
For your set this will only consist of a single vector $v$, thus we have that:
$$\text{Span}\{v\}=\{u \; |\;u = c v  \text{ for} \; c \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
If this vector is identically the zero vector ($v \equiv 0$), then the spanning set is:
$$\text{Span}\{ 0\} = \{u | u = c \cdot 0 \text{ for} c \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{0\}$$
This is a single point and so has dimension zero. For the nonzero vector we have the original  set:
$$\{u \; |\;u = c v  \text{ for} \; c \in \mathbb{R} \}$$
Since c is a real number it is allowed to be zero and as such the vector $u=0$ is in the span of $v$. As are all multiples of $v$, this forms a straight line in space and is thus 1 dimensional.

Comment: Only quibble here would be the exercise doesn't specify that the field is $\mathbb R$, but the argument holds if you replace it with an arbitrary field :)

Comment: True, I did make the assumption for a more undergrad oriented class..wherein I had only ever seen the real numbers used. I should say over a field K

Comment: Hello @Dan. In Linear Algebra, Is the number "0" implied to be the zero vector?

Comment: I find that it can be context sensitive, i.e. usually one can determine from the text when a constant multiplier is zero instead of a vector being a zero vector, typically I have seen the zero vector represented as a bold zero or a zero with an arrow over it. In the above all those zeros are the zero vector

Comment: I scored 22/25 on the final :)

Comment: Excellent to hear hopefully this helped you